# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.alightcreative.motion signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring

Tags: android, app-store, apk

I cant install an app (alight motion) from play store. I downloaded it using an apk last time but after a software update it just disappeared. I tried installing it again using an apk, it just says app not installed. Tried doing it through the google play store too, it downloads until 100% but then just says cant install.

I used SAI to try and download the apk again. This was the message I got:

INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.alightcreative.motion signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

However I could not find any app or file package. What do I do? Please help, I would really appreciate it:)